# flyway hsql db create tables sql migrate hangs

Tags: sql, hsqldb, flyway

I am executing flyway using maven.
I have a sql(It has DDL create tables - DEPARTMENT , EMPLOYEE as shown below) 
I run `mvn compile flyway:migrate`

Here is the console log.

```
......
[INFO] Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.097s)
[DEBUG] Schema "PUBLIC" already exists. Skipping schema creation.
[DEBUG] Locking table "PUBLIC"."schema_version"...
[DEBUG] Lock acquired for table "PUBLIC"."schema_version"
[INFO] Current version of schema "PUBLIC": 1
[INFO] Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.1 - department
[DEBUG] Found statement at line 2: CREATE TABLE Department (
ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)
)
[DEBUG] Found statement at line 8: CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) PRIMARY KEY ,
NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
DEPARTMENTID INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PUBLIC.DEPARTMENT(ID)
)
[DEBUG] Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE Department (
ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)
)
```

The execution hangs after first create table i.e Department table.
Then I kill using ctrl+C I see schema_version and Department table alone gets created.

I tried other ways of  create table i.e  without ID Generation ,  adding ';' at end , adding GO after each CREATE TABLE but it did not help.

The same create table sql runs successfully using Squirrel SQL client.
I am using flyway version 4.0.3 and hsqldb 2.3.4.
On debug it is seen that it is waiting for response I/O from DB to complete at this point => 
 boolean hasResults = statement.execute(sql); within the class org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned by Fredt , this issue is not seen when using hsqldb-2.3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is specific to HSQLDB 2.3.4 which has more strict locking. You can set the transaction model to MVCC to avoid the issue. Alternatively use HSQLDB version 2.3.3.

Comment: How do I set this . I have tried specifying the jdbc url in flyway properties in this ways : jdbc:hsqldb:file:db1;hsqldb.tx=mvcc OR jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db1;hsqldb.tx=mvcc , but I see no difference.        I used same above url in squirrel client to login and after login in the meta data - client properties I still see hsqldb.tx as LOCKS and not MVCC.

Comment: And yes I don't see this issues with 2.3.3. Temporarily I could use this , however i need to get this working with 2.3.4. In my case fly way seems to run the sql so I am trying to find out how I can do it either at server or database level . Also with 2.3.3 when I check in squirrel client the meta info - client properties I still see hsqldb.tx is LOCKS and no issues here

Comment: See the HSQLDB Guide on servers. You need to append the `hsqldb.tx=mvcc` or any other properties to the database files path in server properties.

Comment: As far as I can tell, setting `hsqldb.tx=mvcc` doesn't help. Also, when 2.3.3 (which works in its default configuration) is configured to use MVCC it hangs as well. I've shared a sample that reproduces the problem and a summary of my findings on GitHub: https://github.com/wilkinsona/flyway-hsqldb-hang

Comment: I could sucessfully run HSQLDB with MVCC transactions but changing the model to LOCKS during the Flyway migration (it works with LOCKS only but my applications requires MVCC) by using the **Flyway callbacks** *beforeMigrate* and *afterMigrate*, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39274854/2043553.